# How can I make my work from home table interesting and comfy

Tags: comfort, efficiency, bedroom, office

I'm looking for a change but don’t know what to change, deal? Chair or just both? I find myself pulling laptop and putting it on my knee and raising to eye level (see image below). Which is annoying but so is sitting with it on table.

[image: supporting laptop with knee to level to eye]

What can attribute to my distraction and uncomfortable work from home environment?

Another thing is that as I don’t have much space to spare another room, my bedroom corner is my office and I sit all day:

[image: the bedroom corner]

Comment: Working from home is quite different to working in an office, and one thing you might need to change is your *attitude* to the work you do, not just how you sit. If that can happen, you might find the slouched working position isn't very conducive to creativity. Would it be, in an office?

Comment: @WeatherVane I have found I been sitting in slouched position mostly my life, it is the way the posture had been, so 25 yrs after it is a default, but yes u r right, in office slouched is not much, the difference is work area, they r bright, comfortable seat. chair and monitor arms but I cannot find why is so demotivating about my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make this an answer rather than a comment under Weather Vane's answer…

I agree with all that Weather Vane already said, but that desk is not conducive to any work environment at all. It's too small, probably too low, you're looking out of the window, with the light behind your screen.
A laptop is a very poor substitute for a desktop & large display[s].

Losing the armrests might make you pay more attention to what you're supposed to be doing. Your chair is tilted back for relaxation, not work.
If your 'working posture' is laid back with your laptop on your knees, you've already checked out, like some early 2k's 'dotcom' with bean bags & a play area. That was a work ethic that didn't actually last.

Overall, it looks more like a student's bedroom than an office. You have nowhere to put anything. No shelving, no filing, the desk is too small to work at.

Make it into an office - even if it's only an office when you are facing the desk & can't see the rest of the room. At minimum, turn 90° clockwise so you're facing the wall,  not gazing out of the window or twisting to face the open room. Sit up, don't lie back. You're approaching your day like it was a day off.
Focus.

Comment: I too thought of turning the desk. They might need another desk too, so the printer isn't taking up half the space.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. That isn’t printer @WeatherVane . It’s a desktop stand from IKEA. Ur answer reminded me of desk I had but it was too big for room and my wife has problem as it looked more office then bedroom. I was more able to focus more on it.

Answer (score 1):

I worked from home for 25 years, after working in an office for 10.

There are some differences between working at home or in company premises (and in my case there *wasn't* an office I could check in to).

- No 'travel to work' period where you get into the right frame of mind.
- No office manager keeping an eye on you.
- No colleagues to help the day flow.
- A lot of distractions at home.

You might find it is the home environment itself that is draining your motivation. What I found is that in the morning, if I let myself get distracted by anything, it would be very hard to get started, and even then I could not focus properly.

I realised I had to set a **routine** if I wanted to **achieve** anything. I am sharpest in the morning, so that is when I must do the jobs that need close attention. And when I tire, I can't walk away from a part day if there is stuff to do. But as you will see, I kind-of let myself do that.

- After breakfast take my coffee to the 'office' and begin to engage my brain. Write a list of the things I need to do first, and some less important things. Start thinking about the item at top of the list.
- If I want the radio on, tune to a current affairs program or something business-like. No music, nothing that says 'easy now'.
- Get stuck in. Tell other any other people that I must not be disturbed.
- Apart from more coffee, take a break around midday. Not 15 minutes, but a couple of hours. Get out of the house, take exercise, buy groceries, etc. Enjoy the day.
- Go back to the desk. Take a look at less demanding things on the list. Play with ideas. Make plans. Network. Play music. Wind down. Review what I achieved today, or didn't.

The most important thing of all, was that I had to **take charge** of and **organise** my working life. I don't suppose my routine will suit you exactly, but I hope you can get some inspiration from it.

Comment: SE Lifehacks isn't about recommending any particular desk, chair or lighting but thinking *out of the box* and that is what I intended my answer to get you do.